# regular expression for extracting time

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract time from a text whatever format it might be.for eg: this

1) 06/02/2009: On Tuesday morning at about 08:30 am, in Nazran, Ingushetia, Russia, an improvised explosive device (IED) that had been placed under a vehicle belonging to Lt. Colonel Isa Tochiyev, the chief of personal security for the republic's anti-drug department, exploded as the police officer was driving with his family on Moskovskaya Street, killing the police officer, wounding two children and damaging the vehicle. The IED was filled with 100 to 200 grams of explosives.

output

08:30 am

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}[.:]\\d{2}\\s?[AaPp]\\.?[Mm])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find())
 {
 System.out.println("The time is " + m.group(0));
 }
```

Can anyone help me instead of giving serialized down voting.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regex does not take into account that there might be dot separators in your time stamps; nor that there might be dots in the AM/PM stamp.

To match all of the instances in your examples, try:

```
\d{1,2}[.:]\d{2}\s?[AaPp]\.?[Mm]
```

**EDIT**
The OP has added some additional possible formats to his time stamps.  To account for those, try:

```
\d{1,2}(?:[:.]\d{2}){1,2}(?:\s?[AaPp]\.?[Mm])?
```

This regex looks for a pattern that

starts with one or two digits
then a time separator of either a dot or a colon
   followed by two digits -- repeated once or twice (for just minutes, or minutes+seconds)
Then an optional space followed by AM or PM (either case) with or without a dot after the A

Comment: this shows the error "invalid escape sequence"

Comment: @chopu Are you using a different language than what you originally reported?  You did not mention getting that error with your original code (and not indicating the results from your code is probably the reason for the downvote).  Java usually requires escaping the backslash in order for it to be properly interpreted.  So instead of \d, you might need \\d (and similar for the other special characters).  But you did NOT indicate that kind of problem with your example.

Comment: thank u Ron..it's working...i have one more doubt what if the time is in hr:min:sec format eg:08:30:50 am..it identifies only 30:50 am

Comment: @chopu That is because you provided neither an example in that format, nor a comprehensive description of the possible formats.  See my Edited answer for a possible solution

Comment: thanks Ron for helping me..+1 for answering...I understood my mistake and had editted my question in a proper way..but it does not works for format 9 am.

Comment: is this ok for making the min and sec optional Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2}$(?:[:.]\\d{2}){1,2}$(?:\\s?[AaPp]\\.?[Mm])?");

Comment: @chopu What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it doesn't shows error....but i have to make the min and sec optional...bcoz for an i/p like 4 pm otherwise it doesn't work..Genuinely I'm not good in regex..plz help me Ron

Comment: @chopu It did not work here at all.  You are showing a $ character in several areas.  That usually means end of line or end of string.  I would just add it as an alternation at the end.  If you make minutes and seconds and AM/PM all optional, then you will pick up any numbers, whether or not they are part of a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55055/discussion-between-chopu-and-ron-rosenfeld).